# Can not convert std::string to date type

Tags: c++, date, c++11

I am using [Howard Hinnant's date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) and trying to convert `std::string` to `date::year_month_day` using piece of code shown below.

```
#include "date.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  std::string d = "2016-11-23";
  std::istringstream in{d};
  date::sys_days sd;
  date::parse(in, "%F", sd);
  date::year_month_day ymd = sd;
  std::cout << ymd << '\n';
}
```

And receiving too many error complaining about `‘const class std::time_get<char>’ has no member named ‘get`

```
In file included from convert_string_to_date.cpp:1:0:
date.h: In instantiation of ‘void date::detail::parse(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits>&, date::local_time<Duration>&, std::basic_string<CharT, Traits>*, std::chrono::minutes*) [with CharT = char; Traits = std::char_traits<char>; Duration = std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<86400l, 1l> >; date::local_time<Duration> = std::chrono::time_point<date::local_t, std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<86400l, 1l> > >; std::chrono::minutes = std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<60l> >]’:
date.h:4371:90:   required from ‘void date::detail::parse(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits>&, date::local_time<Duration>&, std::chrono::minutes*) [with CharT = char; Traits = std::char_traits<char>; Duration = std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<86400l, 1l> >; date::local_time<Duration> = std::chrono::time_point<date::local_t, std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<86400l, 1l> > >; std::chrono::minutes = std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<60l> >]’
date.h:4447:42:   required from ‘void date::parse(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits>&, date::sys_time<Duration>&) [with CharT = char; Traits = std::char_traits<char>; Duration = std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<86400l, 1l> >; date::sys_time<Duration> = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<86400l, 1l> > >]’
date.h:4649:59:   required from ‘void date::parse(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const CharT*, date::sys_time<Duration>&) [with CharT = char; Traits = std::char_traits<char>; Duration = std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<86400l, 1l> >; date::sys_time<Duration> = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<86400l, 1l> > >]’
convert_string_to_date.cpp:12:27:   required from here
date.h:4192:21: error: ‘const class std::time_get<char>’ has no member named ‘get’
                     f.get(is, 0, is, err, &tm, b, i-1);
                     ^
date.h:4197:25: error: ‘const class std::time_get<char>’ has no member named ‘get’
                         f.get(is, 0, is, err, &tm, ymd, ymd+8);
                         ^
date.h:4211:21: error: ‘const class std::time_get<char>’ has no member named ‘get’
                     f.get(is, 0, is, err, &tm, b, i-1);
                     ^
date.h:4221:25: error: ‘const class std::time_get<char>’ has no member named ‘get’
                         f.get(is, 0, is, err, &tm, hm, hm+6);
                         ^
date.h:4266:25: error: ‘const class std::time_get<char>’ has no member named ‘get’
                         f.get(is, 0, is, err, &tm, hm, hm+2);
                         ^
date.h:4275:21: error: ‘const class std::time_get<char>’ has no member named ‘get’
                     f.get(is, 0, is, err, &tm, b, i-1-modified);
                     ^
date.h:4322:21: error: ‘const class std::time_get<char>’ has no member named ‘get’
                     f.get(is, 0, is, err, &tm, b, i-1);
                     ^
date.h:4343:17: error: ‘const class std::time_get<char>’ has no member named ‘get’
                 f.get(is, 0, is, err, &tm, b, e);
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xJZ67flDFWAOF7cu  maybe you have a bad copy of date.h?  Try updating.

Comment: `std::time_get::get` requires C++11, maybe you need a compiler switch to enable C++11

Comment: @xaxxon : I cloned the repository few minute back.

Comment: @KarstenKoop : I have enabled that flag. I am compiling using `g++ -std=c++14 convert_string_to_date.cpp`

Comment: the line numbers in the error message don't line up with what I see in the repo.  For example:   date.h 4183 https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/date.h#L4183

Comment: Oh.   ok, let me check again.

Comment: what compiler and version? (sometimes g++ is aliased to something else like clang)

Comment: @xaxxon : `g++ 4.9.2`.

Comment: Let me update the gcc and check, if it works. What alternative do you suggest ?

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: bluntly, and wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`gcc 4.9` doesn't have the complete `time_get` support that `date.h` requires. It works on gcc 5.